# Installing ngx-bootstrap with ng add command

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, npm, angular-cli, ngx-bootstrap

I am using `angular 8` and I want to install `ngx bootstrap` with `ng add ngx-bootstrap` command, but after running the command I get the following in console output:

```
       Added "bootstrap
       Added "ngx-bootstrap
       Installing packages...
Cannot determine project target configuration for: test.
```

Does anyone know how to fix this error?

Comment: Are you in the project's directory? Just tried it in the new project and all works fine

Comment: Yes, I am in the root directory where package.json is located.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
$ npm install ngx-bootstrap --save
```

Cheers

Comment: I know that one works, I used it before, but I want to use ng add.

Comment: Try see that you're in correct project, ng add ngx-XXXX works fine at the moment...

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding u have remove the **test** project's configuration object while removing the dependencies of **karma** from
**angular.json** file, which is causing the error.

I dont think there is any work arround. You need to manually install it.